# Proper Way of Searching in React with debounce

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, lodash

I have a problem searching using `debounce` in lodash. I'm using React, Material Ui and formik.
It says `TypeError: Expected a function` in

`const debounceLoadData = useCallback( debounce(dispatch(getPersons(10, 1, filter)), 1000), [] );`

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

const debounceLoadData = useCallback(
  debounce(dispatch(getPersons(10, 1, filter)), 1000),
  []
);

const onSearchVoter = (value) => {
  setFilter(value);
  debounceLoadData(value);
};

<Autocomplete
  value={values.voter_id}
  options={persons ? persons : []}
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option === value}
  getOptionLabel={(person) =>
    person
      ? [person?.fname, person?.mname, person?.lname].filter(Boolean).join(" ")
      : ""
  }
  onChange={(e, value) => {
    setFieldValue("voter_id", value ? value : "");
  }}
  onInputChange={async (event, value) => {
    onSearchVoter(value);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      name="voter_id"
      label="Voter"
      variant="outlined"
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      helperText={touched.voter_id ? errors.voter_id : ""}
      error={touched.voter_id && Boolean(errors.voter_id)}
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_.debounce()` function expects another function, and not the result of calling `dispatch`. You should wrap the dispatch call in an arrow function, and pass the filter value via the parameter `value`, and not as a dependency. In addition, add `getPerson` and `dispatch` as dependencies to the `useCallback`.

Note: the `getPerson` function should also be memoized (via `useMemo` or `useCallback`).

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

const debounceLoadData = useCallback(
  debounce(value => dispatch(getPersons(10, 1, value)), 1000),
  [getPersons, dispatch]
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ori. by the way, I'm only using `debounce` in lodash. Should I install the `npm i lodash` package?

Comment: Yes you do, but if you don't use anything else from lodash, you can install [npm.lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) instead, or just use a custom [debounce hook](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not find `useCallback` useful in debounce case. Instead use `useMemo` to create a fixed instance for `dispatch` (with fixed/variable input arguments).

```
  const debouceLoadData = useMemo(() => {
    return debounce(f => {
      dispatch(getPersons(10, 1, f))
    }, 1000)
  }, [dispatch])
```

Now you can even do debounceLoadData(f) if you want to.

NOTE: the reason why `useCallback` doesn't work is that, practically you want to `setState(v)`, the `v` is a variable. And also you don't want to invoke `dispatch` or `getPersons` when you are constructing the debounce. You only want to construct the instance, such as `() => {}` which is what `useMemo` covers.

This is a subtlety. But you can try `useCallback` first.